# Understanding nature of parameters of sklearn.metrics.classification_report

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I came across following piece of code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = [2,1,1,1]
y_pred = [False,True,False,True]
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00         0
           1       1.00      0.67      0.80         3
           2       0.00      0.00      0.00         1

    accuracy                           0.50         4
   macro avg       0.33      0.22      0.27         4
weighted avg       0.75      0.50      0.60         4
```

I am unable to understand how sklearn performs mapping between labels in `y_true` and `y_pred` arrays. That is, how it determines, whether `False` is same as `2` or `1` and same is the case with `True`?

I did not found any details in the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, `True=1` and `False=0`.
So,

```
y_pred = [False,True,False,True]
```

means the same as

```
y_pred = [0,1,0,1]
```

This means, this code will yield exactly the same results as your code:

```
y_true = [2,1,1,1]
y_pred = [0,1,0,1]
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```